# UITableViewCell увеличить высоту ячейки

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Как увеличить высоту ячейки по клику?

В `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` по индексу ячейки увеличить высоту и чтобы было с анимацией добавить `beginUpdates` и `endUpdates` в `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSMutableSet *bigCells; //  не забыть заинитить множество!
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([self.bigCells containsObjects:indexPath]) {
        [self.bigCells removeObject:indexPath];
    } else {
        [self.bigCells addObject:indexPath];
    }
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([self.bigCells containsObject:indexPath]) {
        return 88.0;
    } else {
        return 44.0;
    }
}
```